# How are Hamilton function and Hamilton-Jacobian-Bellman function related to each other?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, dynamic-programming, optimal-control

Can someone here knowing Finnish help me with this question in mathematical physics? I am trying to understand the solution to the problem 2:

[here]
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96742826/School/DY_ratkaisut190214.pdf) that uses the Hamilton conditions for the HJB. I don't understand how the Hamilton conditions can be used with the Hamilton-Jacobian-Bellman equations.

**Questions**

> *1. How are the HJB conditions and Hamilton conditions related to each other?*
>
> *2. When are the HJB conditions and Hamilton conditions the same?*
>
> *3. When is the Euler equation sufficient condition? With fixed end points' problem? Euler equation is below (Kirk p.148).* $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \dot x}$$

**Necessary Conditions for the Hamilton equation**

> $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u}=0$
>
> $\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=-\dot p^*(t)$
>
> $f=\dot x^*(t)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$

**Equations**

> **Hamilton equation**
>
> > $H(x,u,p)=g(x,u)+p'f(x,u)$
> >
> > where $f(x,u)=\dot x$ is the system function, $p$ is the "liittomuuttuja"
>
> **HJB equation (continuous case, compare to Discreate DP case [p.3](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mitchell/Class/CS532M.2007W2/Talks/hjbSham.pdf))**
>
> > $0=\min_{u\in U}\{g(x,u)+\nabla_t V(t,x)+\nabla_x V(T,x)'f(x,u)\}$